# Minimum set of libraries required to use Jackrabbit JCR implementation?

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr, content-repository

I am planning to user Jackrabbit for developing an online document library.
To develop simple POCs, i have put the `jackrabbit-standalone.jar` inside my class path and everything works fine.

But on opening the `jackrabbit-standalone.jar`, i found out that it's a web project in itself.
I copied all the jars from `jackrabbit-standalone.jar/WEB-INF/lib` and kept in my class path and my project again works fine.

My concern here is that I don't want to keep any extra jars in my project. So my question is :

- What are the minimal jars which are required to interact with
  Jackrabbit repository?
- What is the best way of using jackrabbit in a web project, as per enterprise standards. Is it using standalone jar in the class path or using only the required jars?

Answer (score 1):

I won't ask why you want cut out unnecessary jars for a POC.

Do you use maven? If so, you just add jackrabbit-core and it will pull down dependencies.

If you require the JCR API you'll also need jackrabbit-spi2jcr.

Otherwise, this is what we end up with (version 2.6.4):

- commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
- commons-dbcp-1.3.jar
- commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
- concurrent-1.3.4.jar
- jackrabbit-api-2.6.4.jar
- jackrabbit-core-2.6.4.jar
- jackrabbit-jcr-commons-2.6.4.jar
- jackrabbit-spi-2.6.4.jar
- jackrabbit-spi-commons-2.6.4.jar
- jackrabbit-spi2jcr-2.6.4.jar
- jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar
- jcr-2.0.jar
- log4j-1.2.16.jar
- lucene-core-3.6.0.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar
- tika-core-1.3.jar

You can dispense with the logging jars if not needed. Not sure if you can get rid of lucene-core as I believe it's used internally.

Regarding how to use jackrabbit, that's entirely up to you. You can use it as [standalone server](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/standalone-server.html) or, like us, as your persistence layer. We use the JCR api.

Comment: Still tells you in that link

Answer (score 1):

you can use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) to manage dependencies for you.

If you are using maven, you can find out the dependency tree with command :

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

and review the relations between artifacts.

And you can exclude parts you don't want with exclude expressions:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
      <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```